# How to get an american TikTok from another country?

Tags: tiktok

(i want it cause tiktok is geography dependent)

i think about this scheme:

1. i create the account from browser from my PC throw VPN (US)
2. i set a phone number of my US partner
3. he tells me a confirmation code
4. i confirm the account
5. i upload videos from browser from PC throw VPN

the problems:

1. i suspect that PC (or PC uploaded videos) have kind of penalty on tiktok
2. will tiktok trust VPN's IP not trusting my IP it can (probably) get from my browser?
3. where is a place to find this US partner? (maybe for a money reward) (i have no friends in US)

Answer (score -2):

You can use a VPN. A browser's private browsing mode will prevent data from being stored on a user’s local device or computer. However, it does not necessarily prevent information from being shared between the user’s device or computer and their ISP. Furthermore, third parties may be able to detect users’ activity through private browsing sessions, which they can use to exploit their operating system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).